# How to use Micrometer @Timed annotation outside of Spring, in a Java Application

Tags: java, annotations, instrumentation, micrometer

I am trying to use [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) to record info in my Java application.

I have Micrometer registry in my application main initialized as follows:

```
MeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
```

I have a class **CountedObject** which has an int id and a reference to the **registry**.

In my class **CountedObject** I have a method called **timedFunction()** as follows:

```
@Timed(value = "myTimer")
public void timedFunction() {
    try {
        int sleepTime = new Random().nextInt(5) + 1;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("timedFunction");
}
```

And a method called **timedFunction()** as follows:

```
public void timeConsumingFunction() {
    LongTaskTimer longTaskTimer = AppMetrics.getInstance().getLongTaskTimer("longTaskTimer1");
    Sample task = longTaskTimer.start();
    
    try {
        int sleepTime = new Random().nextInt(5) + 1;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    
    System.out.println("timeConsumingFunction() for object-" + id + " took: " + task.duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    task.stop();
}
```

In my application I create an object **CountedObject** and run both methods.

Then I run the following to print all metrics info:

```
List<Meter> meters = registry.getMeters();
    
for (Meter meter : meters) {
    System.out.println(meter.getId());
    for (Measurement measurement : meter.measure()) {
        System.out.println(measurement.getStatistic() + " : " + measurement.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

I only find **"longTaskTimer1"** in the metrics and **myTimer** used in the annotated method is not there. How can this **@Timed** annotation be used and how to link it to my app's register

Answer (score 1):

You need to set-up `TimedAspect` to process `@Timed` annotations.
If you are using Spring, just create a `TimedAspect` `@Bean` and it should work. If you don't, you need to set-up AspectJ yourself.

Comment: When implementing my annotation `@Measured` and `MeasuredAspect` that intercepts my annotation it works. But what I need to use mircometer's `TimedAspect`